# Debugging a world of hell when trying to install MySQL-Python on Mac OS X

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-python

I've been trying for weeks and weeks to install MySQL-python with absolutely no luck, on Mac OS X 10.6 with Python 7.0 from the Enthought Python Distribution. Many of the issues I ran into have been described in other posts and I'm pretty sure I read all of those, but still cannot fix this issue. I tried installing and reinstalling various MySQL packages for 64bit OS X but finally just compiled it from scratch.  MySQL, as far as I know, works and lives in the directory /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86/.

I was able to install MySQL-python-1.2.3 using "sudo setup.py install". However, when I import it, I get the error:

```
$ python
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.0-2 (64-bit)

Python 2.7.1 |EPD 7.0-2 (64-bit)| (r271:86832, Dec  3 2010, 15:56:20) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5488)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/foo/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/foo/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I looked to see, as other posters on here suggested, what _mysql.so is referencing using otool:

```
$ otool -L /Users/foo/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
/Users/foo/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so:
    libmysqlclient.18.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 438.0.0)
```

The correct file seems to exist here:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  3539752 Jan 20  2011 /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
```

I tried several approaches to make _mysql.so recognize this file:

1. Making symbolic links, as others suggested, to the right file:

   $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

when I do this, I get a new error:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/foo/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/foo/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

1. Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, as follows (after removing the previous symbolic link):

   $ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86/lib/

Then I get the same error as initially:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/foo/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/foo/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

1. I also tried as Ned suggested to use install_name_tool to modify the reference

   from ~/.python-eggs directory:

   *trying to change 18 to 16:*
   $ sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86/libmysqlclient.16.dylib _mysql.so

   *approach 2: trying to change 18 to 18:*
    sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib _mysql.so

When I try these, I get the error:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_mysql)
```

Any ideas on what can be done to fix this?  I'd really like to get this package working... I tried for a while and could not get it to work. I understand it's a common issue but I could not get any of the posted solutions to work.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I empathize with your pain, but I think you should ask over at superuser, or at apple.stackexchange.com. The latter has fewer users, probably less technical though, so superuser seems a better place for your administrative package-related question.